# <input type="file" works good but when the file has some blanks in the name PHP failes

Tags: php, html, input, types

`input type=file`

prompts and lets us to select multiple files as "file objects".
One of the file object property is "name" but it is read-only.
When I use PHP in JS with AJAX and FormData, it works great but when there is a space(s) in the file name, it does sometimes one or two but fails most of the time.
Now in PHP, it is paired

`$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']` (size, type the other values)

```
 and isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])
```

fails, if not I will use `str_replace(" ","%",$name);` but isset fails (Still trying to find out why?)

1. Is it possible to modify input type=file selected file objects' name?
2. If there is no solution for 1, how to be able to pass `isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])` obstacle to do `str_replace(" ","%",$name)` in PHP;

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I follow, but it would seem the main problem are spaces in filenames? Adding enctype=multipart/form-data to the form may help. Else, I'd take the value of the filename and filter it through one of the replace functions, converting spaces to something else, like

```
$filename = str_replace(' ', '-', $filename);
```

before letting the script continue. Spaces typically read as %20.

Comment: PHP side issues was not related to the "spaces" in the name but sometimes their sizes was larger than php.ini file values. So It was fixed when I changed them up. Since File Object Name is ready only, I don't think I can do anything to modify them in JavaScript so I will use String Replace "blank" with "%20" in PHP for HTML to download/open the related files. (If HTML5 file object's name can be changed, it is good to know though). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `PHP` is smart enough to upload filename containing spaces.

Plus you said it works sometimes, it must be something  else causing an issue.

You can use `is_uploaded_file()` to check for uploads, and use dump `$_FILE` to to debug it

```
if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) {
    print_r($_FILES)
}
```

You will see error if they exist